# TCP/UDP Connection States documentation

Tags: networking, tcpip, session

Does anyone know where to find documentation for TCP/UDP connection states? Preferably non-Microsoft with unix backing.

Basically, I'm looking for more information about TCP established, TCP syn_sent, TCP close, UDP assured, etc. network states.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) (TCP) and [RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) (UDP).

Comment: There's really no other answer to this question.